# Scrolling of Pivot inside Grid

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am trying to create a page that has an outer grid that splits the page in half with a pivot in on of the grid columns.

Code:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


        <Pivot Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
            <Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="18" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
            <PivotItem x:Name="Tab1" Header="Tab 1">
                <ListView x:Name="matchesList">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Data">
                            <Grid>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Match}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </PivotItem>
            <PivotItem x:Name="Tab2" Header="Tab 2">

            </PivotItem>
        </Pivot>
</Grid>
```

I would like the pivot item to scroll. I have tried placing the scrollviewer around lots of the inside elements but around the entire pivot is the only way it shows up. The ListView populates correctly but just runs off the end of the screen and is still not scroll-able. How can I get the ListView to scroll inside the pivot?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using outer scrollviewer, when listview has its own? As I've tried the code seems like the list should be scrollable along with horizontal pivot. You may try to use `ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled="True"` (or vertical depending on situation).

Comment: Sorry, I have removed that from my code as it did not change anything. What I am trying to do is have the ListView inside the PivotItem scroll vertically. The data lists vertically but just flows off the screen..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've tired, if you enable [IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ScrollViewer#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_ScrollViewer_IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled), it should work:

```xml
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


    <Pivot Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
        <Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="18" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <PivotItem x:Name="Tab1" Header="Tab 1">
            <ListView x:Name="matchesList" ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled="True">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Data">
                        <Grid>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Match}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </PivotItem>
        <PivotItem x:Name="Tab2" Header="Tab 2">

        </PivotItem>
    </Pivot>
</Grid>
```

Generally scrolling *ScrollViewer* is handled on a very low level to gain performance. Though this has also some disadvantages - it brings problems when you want to use *PointerEvents*. To make life easier, two properties have been designed - vertical/horizontal chaining - this allows to pass vertical/horizontall scroll from child to parent - like in your example - *ListView* scrolls vertically and *Pivot* horizontally.

Comment: Ok! So if I define a row height in the outside grid for the row the pivot is in (Height="200") this code works and the scroll bar shows up. Apparently the problem is that the outside grid is extending down off the window to accommodate the list view size and thus not scrolling since it is on auto height. Is there a way to get the grid to fit to the window and not flow off screen?

Comment: I resolved the problem! This page was being displayed inside a splitview frame. I needed to define a Grid around my splitview object and place it in a row with `Height="*"`. The content then sized correctly and scrolled!

Comment: @KennyWitham Good to hear that you solved the problem.